# Grid layout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to achieve the following layout:

[image: Target layout]

Using [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) in `Android`. How should I approach it?

Comment: Is this one Cell layout?

Comment: This can be achieved using Fragments

Comment: your grid item is static or dynamic ?